# How to create right angle number triangle using python

Tags: python

- Need to create right angle number triangle
- every vacant is filled with zeros
- if I am appending to the list and return the list , my output is not proper

code is below

```
def right_angle(lines):
    result = []
    result = [[0 for i in range(lines)] for i in range(lines)]
    for i in range(lines):
        for j in range(lines-i-1):
            print(" ",end=" ")
        for j in range(i+1):
            print(j+ 1, end=' ')
        print( )
    #return result
right_angle(4)
```

My out

```
      1 
    1 2 
  1 2 3 
1 2 3 4
```

Expected is

```
[[0 0 0 1] 
[0 0 1 2] 
[0 1 2 3] 
[1 2 3 4]]
```

Comment: You're not updating the lists at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing spaces and numbers, append `0` and numbers in your loops.

And you should append `lines-i` `0`'s, not `lines-i-1`.

```
def right_angle(lines):
    result = []
    for i in range(lines):
        row = []
        for j in range(lines-i):
            row.append(0)
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            row.apend(j)
        result.append(row)
    retrn result
```

This can be simplified to:

```
def right_angle(lines):
    result = []
    for i in range(lines):
        result.append([0] * (lines-i) + list(range(1, i+1)))
    return result
```

Comment: if i want to start from left `[[0 0 0 1] 
[0 0 2 1] 
[0 3 2 1] 
[4 3 2 1]]` what need to be done

Comment: `range(i, 0, -1)` will go in reverse

Comment: result.append([0] * (lines-i-1) + list(range(i,0,-1))), for reversing i got `[[0, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]`  but actual is `[[0, 0, 1 ], [0, 2, 1 ], [3, 2 ,1 ] ]`

Comment: `lines-i-1` should just be `lines-i`

Answer (score 1):

You could probably condense this a bit, but it works. You literally just forgot to add the `[]` and did `' '` instead of `'0 '`.

```
def right_angle(lines):
    result = []
    result = [[0 for i in range(lines)] for i in range(lines)]
    for i in range(lines):
        if i == 0:
            print('[[',end='')
        else:
            print('[',end='')
        for j in range(lines-i-1):
            print("0",end=" ")
        for j in range(i+1):
            print(j+ 1, end=' ')
        print(']', end='')
        if i == lines-1:
            print(']')
        print( )
    #return result
right_angle(4)
```

Comment: the third bullet in the question says to return a list, not print.